# Parallelize bean class in spark

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

Can we parallelize the bean class in java spark? If yes please provide the syntax for the same. If no then how can we load bean class in JavaRDD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can. Only requirement is that the class must be serializable.

Example:

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    private int x;
    public A() {}
    public A(int x) {this.x = x;}
    // getters and setters
}

// later in main class
import java.util.Arrays;
// later
JavaRDD<A> rdd = javaSparkContext.parallelize(Arrays.asList(new A(5)));
```